# Init.d script doesn't start or stop only prints help message

Tags: linux, bash, shell, init

I've tried to write a custom upstart script for uwsgi emperor but it doesn't seem to start uwsgi and only says `Usage: /etc/init.d/uwsgi {start|stop|reload}` when I try to run it using "service uwsgi start".

Can anyone please tell me where I have gone wrong. The snippet below is from my deployment shell script:

```
cat <<EOF >/etc/init.d/uwsgi
#!/bin/bash
daemon=\$APPVENV/bin/uwsgi
args="--emperor \$APPCONF/uwsgi/app.ini --daemonize /var/log/emperor.log --emperor-pidfile \$APPDIR/emperor.pid --gid `id -g \$APPUSER`"
pid=\$APPDIR/emperor.pid
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon -m -p \$pid --start --exec \$daemon \$args
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping script uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon --signal INT -p \$pid --stop \$daemon \$args
        ;;
    reload)
        echo "Reloading conf"
        kill -HUP \$(cat \$pid)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/uwsgi {start|stop|reload}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
EOF

chmod u+x /etc/init.d/uwsgi
update-rc.d uwsgi defaults
service uwsgi start
```

Comment: You have asked the same question repeatedly, and you are still misquoting the `APP*` variables.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a HERE script? couldn't you just use cp and have a separate file? Have you read /etc/init.d/uwsgi after this script is run? Do you notice anything you didn't expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following. Pay close attention to which `$` I escape and do not escape.

```
cat <<EOF >/etc/init.d/uwsgi
#!/bin/bash
daemon="$APPVENV/bin/uwsgi"
args=( --emperor "$APPCONF/uwsgi/app.ini"
       --daemonize /var/log/emperor.log
       --emperor-pidfile "$APPDIR/emperor.pid" --gid \$(id -g "$APPUSER")
     )
pid="$APPDIR/emperor.pid"
case "\$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon -m -p \$pid --start --exec \$daemon \$args
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping script uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon --signal INT -p \$pid --stop \$daemon \$args
        ;;
    reload)
        echo "Reloading conf"
        kill -HUP \$(< \$pid)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/uwsgi {start|stop|reload}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
EOF

chmod u+x /etc/init.d/uwsgi
update-rc.d uwsgi defaults
service uwsgi start
```

Variables like `APPDIR`, based on your previous questions, are used to configure what is actually written to disk, so you leave them unescaped so that they are expanded when `/etc/init.d/uwsgi` is written.

Variables like `daemon`, `$1`, and the command substitutions `$(id -g "$APPUSER")` are intended to be expanded when the init script *runs*, so you want the literal string `$daemon` to appear in the script, not the value of `$daemon` (which is probably undefined) when `uwsgi` is written.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to escape the `$1` like you did in other places in your script:

```
case "\$1" in
```

As you are using `cat` to create the script, you need to escape all instances of `$`

Comment: Or better yet use `cat<<'EOF'` with single quotes and remove all the escapes.

Comment: Otherwise the backticks will need to be escaped, too.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the service start really does send an argument to your script:

```
*)
    echo "Argument taken was \"$1\"."
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/uwsgi {start|stop|reload}"
    exit 1
```

It could actually be different and you may consider making changes based from it.